# How to integrate Packery JS with "WordPress's query_posts" and Infinitescroll also imagesLoaded JS

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll, packery

I've found really cool script called "Packery" and decide to use this instead of Masonry more famous grid Script.

But there are just few documentation on the script provided site, so I'd really like to know the way of integration this with WordPress query_posts and Infinitescroll also imagesLoaded.

1. packery
2. infinite-scroll
3. imagesloaded

by using of these, I set up sample WP site as below, but it won't work Infinitescroll and doubtfully imagesLoaded too.

index.php/WordPress

```
<div class="packery">   
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="item w2 h2">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
</div>

<div id="infiniteMore">
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Here is the sample site URL http://itadakimasu.sakura.ne.jp/packery/,
It looks Packery and draggy script work fine but infinitescroll must be NO...

and one more I confronted with the matter how to use "progress" animation with imagesLoaded JS when the page loaded without relying on "append option" first, it means when the page loads, then progressively show up the images throughout distracted posts by query_posts.

I found this code as below, but don't know how to reuse this adapted for page loading effect.

reference:http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/xtzmg

```
  // for each loaded image...
  var imgLoad = imagesLoaded( container );
  imgLoad.on( 'progress', function( imgLoad, image ) {
    if ( !image.isLoaded ) {
      return;
    }
    // un-hide item and lay out
    var itemElem = image.img.parentNode;
    classie.remove( itemElem, 'is-hidden' );
    pckry.appended( itemElem );
  });
```

I don't figure out finely usage of append option, so it's so hard for me fix it by myself.

Any help welcome.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://packery.metafizzy.co/ there is a button called download these docs and it has quit a pit of info about Packery and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did scrutinize into that already, but there are no paragraphs mentioned the way of use Infinitescroll integration.

Packery seems quite difficult to use for novice like as me although I bought commercial license.

I wait the author to expand that official document some another few months.

Anyway, Thank you for your indication.